# WHERE clause not functioning as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join some tables to receive some data and it is not working as expected. Here is my query:

```
SELECT USR.PK_User AS PKUser
    ,USR.NAME AS NAME
FROM [User] USR
LEFT JOIN aspnet_Users ASPU ON USR.NAME = ASPU.UserName
LEFT JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles ASPUIR ON ASPU.UserId = ASPUIR.UserId
WHERE ASPUIR.RoleId = 'E8700479-902A-42F1-A500-4FA02CAC356C'
```

Nothing is being returned from this query. But if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM [aspnet_UsersInRoles] WHERE RoleId = 'E8700479-902A-42F1-A500-4FA02CAC356C'
```

I get 76 selected rows. If I just do:

```
SELECT USR.PK_User AS PKUser
    ,USR.NAME AS NAME
FROM [User] USR
LEFT JOIN aspnet_Users ASPU ON USR.NAME = ASPU.UserName
LEFT JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles ASPUIR ON ASPU.UserId = ASPUIR.UserId
```

I get the expected rows returned. Additionally, if I add:

```
WHERE ASPUIR.RoleId IS NULL
```

I get rows back.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the condition in the `ON` not the `WHERE`.

Otherwise you just make it back into an inner join effectively.

```
SELECT USR.PK_User AS PKUser,
       USR.NAME    AS NAME
FROM   [User] USR
       LEFT JOIN aspnet_Users ASPU
         ON USR.NAME = ASPU.UserName
       LEFT JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles ASPUIR
         ON ASPU.UserId = ASPUIR.UserId
            AND ASPUIR.RoleId = 'E8700479-902A-42F1-A500-4FA02CAC356C'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT USR.PK_User AS PKUser,
   USR.NAME    AS NAME
FROM   [User] USR
   LEFT JOIN aspnet_Users ASPU
     ON USR.NAME = ASPU.UserName
   LEFT JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles ASPUIR
     ON ASPU.UserId = ASPUIR.UserId
        AND ASPUIR.RoleId = 'E8700479-902A-42F1-A500-4FA02CAC356C'
```